# Azure Storage protection with custom authentication and Authorization

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to protect my Azure blob storage resources (images, pdf etc.) through my custom authentication. my users are not in Azure AD. What is best practice for that?

Answer (score 0):

Security recommendations for Blob storage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/security-recommendations

You can also use Azure SAS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview
Requiring HTTPS when a client uses a SAS token to access blob data helps to minimize the risk of eavesdropping. For more information, see Grant limited access to Azure Storage resources using shared access signatures (SAS).

Authorize requests to Azure Storage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-requests-to-azure-storage

Acquire a token from Azure AD for authorizing requests from a client application:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet